# Adding event to websocket (onclose, etc.) after it has been initialized by external package without reference to it

Tags: javascript, node.js, browser, websocket

There's an active websocket that has been initialized by an external package (in this case it's `webpack-dev-server`, but it could be any package). Inspecting the browser with devtools and after a first glance at the source code, I can not find any global which gives access to the Websocket object. Is it still possible to add an event to the WebSocket object after it has been initialized when there's no reference to it?

What I would like to do with it is trigger a function to run if the `onclose` listener is called. Re-initializing the websocket to the same port and then adding an event seems hacky.

```js
const ws = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:6060'); // already initialized
```

After the onclose event is successfully called: it gives the warning `WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:6060/' failed: Connection closed before receiving a handshake response`.